# Empty gem list, but can use rails --version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that Rails is a gem. Which means when I run

```
gem list
```

the terminal should echo the name rails for me.

My problem is that I can run

```
rails --version
```

but when it comes to `gem list` I only receive `*LOCAL GAME LIST*` without any text following.

What could be wrong? Is it my understanding?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: How did you install ruby? Did you use rvm, or some other "easy installer"? What is your OS? Windows, linux, OSX?

Comment: Thank you. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I used apt-get, actually, to install Ruby.
The Rail part was "installed" when I cloned a git and run `bundle install --without production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check Your Path and/or Package Manager

If you have Rails installed through your package manager, rather than as a gem, then your local gem list *will* be empty. If you are running Debian or Ubuntu, `dpkg -l rails` will show you whether it's installed as a system package instead.

You can also find which binary you're invoking with `which rails` on the command line. If you did a source install, that may tell you where in your PATH the Rails application is located.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I used apt-get to install Ruby.
The Rail part was "installed" when I cloned a git and run `bundle install --without production`.
It seems strange to me that even though I can use `rails --version`, I cannot do stuffs like `rails server`, even after a fresh `bundle` command.
How can I remove all of the install of RoR, without reinstalling ubuntu?
Thank you and best regards

Comment: just uninstall it like a gem, run `gem uninstall rails`. You should install ruby and rails through RVM. This is for your reference: [Install ruby and rails](http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/05/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) or this [Install rails](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/ubuntu)